# How to disable Google integration in Chrome 28 beta?

Tags: google-chrome

Since the latest Google Chrome beta, Google is everywhere in my browser and I find that very annoying.

New tab:

[image: New tab]

Address bar:

[image: Address bar]

Google results:

[image: Google results]

I looked everywhere in the settings, advanced settings and even in the chrome://flags and I don't see an option to restore the previous behavior.

Thank you.

Comment: Google is in your Google search results? This is an outrage!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to `chrome://flags`.
2. Set **Enable Instant Extended API** to **Disabled**:

   [image]
3. Click **Relaunch Now** at the bottom of the page.

   [image]
4. Everything should be back to what you were used to.

Comment: Thank you! The funny thing is I also have a MacBook, with the exact same Chrome version and configuration (even for this experiment which is also set to "Default"). Do you have any idea why on my iMac "Default" seems to be "Enabled" and not on my MacBook?

Comment: @Pym: Yeah, it is a bit weird. I have the behavior you described in Canary on my laptop, but I didn't have it in Canary on my Desktop. Both are set to default. Not quite sure how this happens.